# Jackson Object Mapper reading objects with variable field/val types

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an object that looks like this

```
{
field1: "val1",
field2: "val2",
field3: {{ val3 }},
field4:{
   x:a,
   y:"b"
}
}
```

so as you can see the fields aren't surrounded by quotes, and some vals aren't. I'm trying to read this object's byte array using Jackson's object mapper like so

`OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(IOUtils.toByteArray(objectContent, Map.class)`
but I'm running into

`[junit] Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name`

I believe it's complaining about the second opening bracket for field3's value.

is there an easy way to parse a json object like this using object mapper?

Answer (score 0):

Since that format is not valid JSON, you will have to create a custom deserializer.

See: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html